# Callin API with AOUTH from VSCode Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, oauth-2.0, oauth, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VSCode Extension.

And I wanna call APIs with OAUTH.

Please tell me how to call or sites showing samples.

=============================

I guess my issue is same with below sled.

[Is it possible to Auth to an OAuth 2.0 API from inside a vscode extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317735/is-it-possible-to-auth-to-an-oauth-2-0-api-from-inside-a-vscode-extension)

But I couldn't get solutions from here.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by myself.
I installed and used 'request' seeing below.
https://stormpath.com/blog/talking-to-oauth2-services-with-nodejs

The apis I would use need requests by 'post'.

Comment: I should search by the words "node.js oauth api". Before noticing this, I've searched by the words "VSCode extention oauth api" and couldn't find answers to resolve.

Comment: But I have a question.

My api manual show the parameter names "clientId", "clientSecret".
But in actually, I needed to specify the name "client_id", "client_secret".

What is the reasons of this difference?